# Trying to have form recall longblob information from MySQL database for file input control

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, input, upload

Hello follow programmers,

I am fairly novice at web design, so please response in kind. I was not able to find a solution in any forum for my unique problem, so I ask my question here.

I have a MySQL database set up and can upload data and images fine. However, I have an admin account that I would like to be able to edit the information in the database through a web form. I have tried many ways to get the form to read information from the database and autofill the form, however I can't get the file input control to "remember" or recall the image that was uploaded. All the other data, such as id, name, etc. work file and autofill, but not the image.

Here is some code that I am using to present and fill the form. I have a strong feeling the error is in the $row else statement. I'm not sure how to go about autofilling the file input element. I left out parts because the entire code is quite lengthly (represented by the ellipses). Let me know if you need more information. Any thoughts or examples would be great. Thank you.

PS - I know mysql_query is depreciated...I will fix that later.

```
//runs when the form needs to display, retaining the values <- abbreviated to make shorter
function renderForm($id, $name, $image, $description, $salePrice, $listPrice, $shipping, $company, $category, $subCategory, $quantity, $type, $newArrival, $vintage, $error){
//if there are any errors...
if ($error != ''){
    //display errors
    echo "<div id=\"newMemberError\">$error</div>\n";
} 

//display the form
echo "<form method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"max_file_size\" value=\"6000000\">\n";
echo "<table id=\"newMemberTable\">\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "  <th><label>ID: <span class=\"aster\">*</span></label></th>\n";
echo "  <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" value=\"$id\"/></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "  <th><label>Name: <span class=\"aster\">*</span></label></th>\n";
echo "  <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"$name\"></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
...
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "  <th><label>Image: <span class=\"aster\">*</span></label></th>\n";
echo "  <td><input type=\"file\" name=\"image\" value=\"data:image/$type;base64,$image\"></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td><img class=\"paginatedImg\" height=\"40\" width=\"50\" src=\"data:image/$type;base64,$image\"></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "  <th><label>Type of Image: <span class=\"aster\">*</span></label></th>\n";
echo "  <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"type\" value=\"$type\"></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "  <th>&nbsp;</th>\n";
echo "  <td><input id=\"newMemberBtn\" type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"><span id=\"requiredMsg\">* required</span></td>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
echo "</form>\n";
}

//check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
...
}
//if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the database and display the form
else{
//get the id value from the URL (if it exists)
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    //query database
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id='$id'")
              or die(mysql_error()); 
    //set variable to hold amount of rows
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    //if the ID matches up with the database...
    if($row){
        //get the data from database
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $image = $row['image'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $salePrice = $row['salePrice'];
        $listPrice = $row['listPrice'];
        $shipping = $row['shipping'];
        $company = $row['company'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $subCategory = $row['subCategory'];
        $quantity = $row['quantity'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $newArrival = $row['newArrival'];
        $vintage = $row['vintage'];

        //display form
        renderForm($id, $name, $image, $description, $salePrice, $listPrice, $shipping, $company, $category, $subCategory, $quantity, $type, $newArrival, $vintage, '');
    }
    //if no match...
    else{
        //display error message to user
        echo "No results!";
    }
}
//if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value...
else{
    //display error message to user
    echo 'Error!';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display the image using the `input` tag because `value` attribute does not apply to `input[type=file]`. see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html.
You could, however, display the image in an image tag:

```
echo "<img src=\"data:image/$type;base64,$image\" />";
```

Comment: I am actually doing that to display the data after submission in a table. All the records are being shown that have been entered. The problem is that say the admin wants to edit an entry, all the data is recalled except for the image, requiring them to upload it again...I'm trying to prevent that, especially because there are a lot of entries to keep track of, it's redundant, and the admin may not have access to the image on the device they are using.

Comment: I see. you can update your php upload handler to keep existing image when no new image is posted.